# Сортировка списка с вложенными словарями. Python

Tags: python, сортировка

У меня есть список с данными о студентах:

```
students = [ 
    {'name': 'Maxim', 'age': 23, 'course': 'excel', 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'name': 'Anna', 'age': 19, 'course': 'word', 'gender': 'Female'},
    {'name': 'Bogdan', 'age': 21, 'course': 'powerpoint', 'gender': 'Male'} 
]
```

Мне нужно отсортировать этот список отдельно по именам, возрасту и курсу студентов с помощью *sorted()* и *lambda*.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Представьте ваше решение на данный момент и укажите, что не получается.

Comment: И что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так и хочется на хамство ответить хамством: "Мне нужно...." -  "Вам нужно -  вы и сортируйте". Но учитывая, что вы новичок (а новичков тут стараются не обижать), и судя по всем - школьного возраста, дам ответ:

Сортировка отдельно, по именам, возрасту и курсу студентов:

```
sorted(students, key=lambda x: x['name'])
sorted(students, key=lambda x: x['age'])
sorted(students, key=lambda x: x['course'])
```

Впредь учтите, что тут коллектив взрослых людей, а не школьников средних классов. И нормы поведения тут соответствующие.